# R language:choose the max element one-on-one of two vectors

Tags: r, comparison

```
a <- c(12,13,32,46,14)
b <- c(9,24,43,32,57)
result <- c(12,24,43,46,57)
```

The vector result is from the comparision between vector a and b.For example,as for the first element of a and b,12 is greater than 9 so the first element of vector result is 12.In order to obtain the vector result,what is the code of R?

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the grey check mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `pmax`:

```
pmax(a, b)
```

But this also makes a good demonstration of `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(a > b, a, b)
```